# Rich Text pictures - how to find and manage them

Tags: files, richtextarea, fileupload, file-storage

is there a way to find and address picture uploaded via Rich text editor?
How they are stored in system?
Can reuse uploaded files somehow in different rich text field?

Comment: Found a similar question on trailblazer community. Check out the answers at https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A8zXfSAJ

Answer (score 0):

The images stored in a RTA field are saved to the ContentReference (*not* ContentDocumentLink, ContentDocument, or ContentVersion) object. Short of performing a [Data Export](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_exportdata.htm&type=5), I couldn't find a way to get access to the full list of files, as this object doesn't support queries and doesn't even appear to have documentation associated with it. I suspect that the system automatically deduplicates the files, such that multiple copies should not take up excessive space. You can display them anywhere that the RTA fields can be displayed.