# Large Text or Rich Text field STORAGE SIZE?

Tags: apex

If I define a Custom Field (TASK, CASE, ACTIVITY) that is either Large Text or Rich Text field and set the size to 32.000 (MAX size possible), would it be compressed on disk when not used?

For example, if I use 1.000 characters of a 32.000 Rich Text field, would my storage count 32.000 or 1.000?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Neither, actually.

SObject records are, for the most part, counted as a flat 2 kB towards your "data storage" space allocation (not to be confused with "file storage" which covers things like the `ContentDocument`). This is true no matter how many fields (of any type, including LongTextArea) your SObject has and no matter how many of those fields your individual record has filled with data.

The exceptions are noted [on this help page](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000383664&type=1) (and even then, most of the exceptions are still 2 kB)

Source: My org has LongTextArea field(s) on `Case`, `Opportunity`, and more.
~900k `Cases` => 1.7 GB of data storage space used
~210k `Opportunities` => 421 MB of data storage space used

In most orgs, I think that the obvious standout is going to be `EmailMessage`, where each record is 2 kB + every byte in the TextBody and HtmlBody fields.

Also, as mentioned by Phil W in the comments, images in rich text fields (which are different from long text area fields) contribute to the "file storage" limit (saved to `ContentReference`, according to [this answer by sfdcfox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/319907/24889))

Comment: Worth explicitly pointing out images in rich text are in file storage, not inline within the rich text.

Comment: @PhilW it is done